# Powershell ,Read from a txt file and Format Data( remove lines, remove blank spaces in between)

Tags: powershell

I am really very new to powershell. I want to use powershell to read a txt file and change it to another format.

1. Read from a txt file.
2. Format Data( remove lines, remove blank spaces in between)
3. Count of records ( "T 000000002" 9 chars)

and then write the output to a new file.

I just started powershell two days ago so I don't know how to do this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Count-Object() {
    begin {
        $count = 0
    }
    process {
        $count += 1
    }
    end {
        $count
    }
}

$a= get-content .\members.txt |  
Foreach-Object { ($_  -replace '\s','') } |
Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace '-','') } |
Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace 'OP_ID','') } | 
Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace 'EFF_DT','') } |
Where-Object { $_ -ne '' }|
set-content  .\newmembers.txt

 $b = Get-Content  .\newmembers.txt |
Count-Object $b 
 "T {0:D9}" -f $b | add-content  .\newmembers.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Reading from a file:

   ```
   Get-Content file.txt
   ```
2. Not quite sure what you want here. `Get-Content` returns an array of strings. You can then manipulate what you get and pass it on. The most helpful cmdlets here are probably `Where-Object` (for filtering) and `ForEach-Object` (for manipulating).

   For example, to remove all blank lines you can do

   ```
   Get-Content file.txt | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' } > file2.txt
   ```

   This can be shortened to

   ```
   Get-Content file.txt | Where-Object { $_ } > file2.txt
   ```

   since an empty string in a boolean context evaluates to `false`.

   Or to remove spaces in every line:

   ```
   Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object-Object { $_ -replace ' ' } > file2.txt
   ```
3. Again, not quite sure what you're after here. Possible things I could think of from your overly elaborate description are something along the lines of

   ```
   $_.Substring(2).Length
   ```

   or

   ```
   $_ -match '(\d+)' | Out-Null
   $Matches[1].Length
   ```

Comment: Just a note: redirection via `>` creates file in Unicode. If you need to specify encoding, use `...| Set-Content filename -encoding Utf8`.

Comment: ... or `Out-File`, similarly. @stej: your “Unicode” meaning “UTF16-LE” in this case :-)

Comment: Hi all your help was very usefull. But I am still trying to figure out how to count the number of lines. i am able to remove spaces  My code so far is
$s = get-content D:\MyScripts\members.txt |  
Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace '-', '') } |
Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace 'OP_ID', '') } | 
Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace 'EFF_DT', '') } |
Where-Object { $_ -ne '' }|
Remove-Spaces $s | set-content D:/MyScripts/nmembers.txt

Comment: @mahmgp: Store the result in a variable, which will be an `Object[]`. It has a `Length` property. You can then proceed saving it to the file. Or you use `Tee-Object` to send it to the file and append a `Measure-Object` at the end of the pipeline. The resulting object has a `Count` property.

Comment: Thanks Rossel, your suggestions were really help full. But Measure did not work for me. it returned the namespace in the output if i used Measure. Therefore i have used Count-Object $b "T {0:D9}" -f $b
Below is my Complete Script.

Comment: Count-object counts num ber of lines and "T {0:D9}" returns the Trailer like this: T 000000002 (2 is number of lines.)

Comment: What about where line is not equal to `''` or whitespace?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Then you adjust the `Where-Object` pipeline part accordingly. I tend to use `? { $_ -replace '\s' }` to filter everything that's either empty or just whitespace. Although I guess `? { [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_) }` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I also like the ? used in place of the where-object to trim it down just that much more.

```
Get-Content file.txt | ?{ $_ } > file2.txt
```